# Combining two SQL ORACLE Select Statements with JOIN and COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I have developed two queries that pull from separate tables in my DB. The first query is:

```
SELECT VEHICLES.vehicleModel, 
COUNT(*) SALES_BY_MODEL
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN VEHICLES ON SALES.vehicleVIN = VEHICLES.vehicleVIN
GROUP BY VEHICLES.vehicleModel
ORDER BY SALES_BY_MODEL DESC;
```

And it's output looks like this:

```
VEHICLEMODEL    SALES_BY_MODEL
spark                        9
accord                       8
focus                        6
xt5                          5
rx                           5
ranger                       5
impala                       5
```

The Second query is:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerZip,
COUNT(*) SALES_BY_ZIP
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON SALES.customerID = CUSTOMERS.customerID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.customerZip
ORDER BY SALES_BY_ZIP DESC;
```

And it's output looks like this:

```
 CUSTOMERZIP     SALES_BY_ZIP
 89523                      6
 04019                      4
 85001                      4
 03038                      4
 13760                      4
 20886                      3
```

I need to combine these two queries into ONE **SELECT** statement. I have tried this, but I was getting some errors regarding the **COUNT** function:

```
SELECT VEHICLES.vehicleModel, CUSTOMERS.customerZip,
COUNT(*) SALES_BY_MODEL, SALES_BY_ZIP
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN VEHICLES ON SALES.vehicleVIN = VEHICLES.vehicleVIN
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON SALES.customerID = CUSTOMERS.customerID
GROUP BY VEHICLES.vehicleModel, CUSTOMERS.customerZip
ORDER BY SALES_BY_MODEL DESC, SALES_BY_ZIP DESC;
```

So I then tried this, but now my counts are WAY off:

```
SELECT VEHICLES.vehicleModel, CUSTOMERS.customerZip,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS SALES_BY_MODEL
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT vehicleVIN FROM SALES
        )
) AS SALES_BY_MODEL,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS SALES_BY_ZIP
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT customerZip FROM CUSTOMERS
        )
) AS SALES_BY_ZIP
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN VEHICLES ON SALES.vehicleVin = VEHICLES.vehicleVIN
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON SALES.customerID = CUSTOMERS.customerID
GROUP BY VEHICLES.vehicleModel, CUSTOMERS.customerZip;
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
VEHICLEMODEL    SALES_BY_MODEL     
escalade                   20       
m3                         15      
spark                      14                
silverado                  13     
durango                    12     
accord                     10     
accent                     9       
sedan deville              2       

CUSTOMERZIP     SALES_BY_ZIP
60068                     10
12550                      9
48045                      8
28115                      7
```

What would be the "proper" way to combine these two queries into one query so they display in a single table as output. The **SALES_BY_MODEL** and **SALES_BY_ZIP** columns should be sorted descending, but the **SALES_BY_MODEL** and **SALES_BY_ZIP** columns are NOT tied to each other, therefore it has no negative effect when keeping them in the same output table.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want. The combination is not obvious.

Comment: Done. Added desired output.

Comment: If you group by two columns, you might have multiple rows with the same car because of different zip codes. Is that expected?

Comment: @clinomaniac, that would be fine, assuming the **COUNT** for the model would be correct, however it seems that the count gets thrown off. What about showing them as two completely separate tables? Would that keep it from listing the same values multiple times?

Comment: In that case, what if the number of makes is different than the number of zips? It will have uneven looking table as the result.

Comment: Uneven is fine by me, but I think the better approach will be to just do two separate lists, one on top of each other for instance. Possible?

Comment: You mean like a UNION?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I'm still very new at this. Not sure how to explain what I'm thinking. Give me a minute, I'll update the original question to reflect the output that I'm thinking.

Comment: @clinomaniac Updated. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out and it works well. Thanks for all of the assistance!

```
WITH
  modelSales AS(
SELECT VEHICLES.vehicleModel, COUNT(*) AS salesByModel, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rankID
  FROM SALES
    INNER JOIN VEHICLES ON SALES.vehicleVIN = VEHICLES.vehicleVIN
    GROUP BY VEHICLES.vehicleModel),

  zipSales AS(
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerZip, COUNT(*) AS salesByZip, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rankID
  FROM SALES
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON SALES.customerID= CUSTOMERS.customerID
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.customerZip)

  SELECT m.vehicleModel, m.salesByModel, z.customerZip, z.salesByZip
FROM modelSales m
  FULL OUTER JOIN zipSales z ON m.rankID = z.rankID
  ORDER BY COALESCE(m.rankID, z.rankID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output like you have mentioned but you will not get the column names in between the two tables like you have shown in the expected result. One workaround for that is to have the type as another column.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT "VEHICLEMODEL" TYPE,
    VEHICLES.vehicleModel, 
    COUNT(*) COUNTS
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN VEHICLES ON SALES.vehicleVIN = VEHICLES.vehicleVIN
GROUP BY VEHICLES.vehicleModel
UNION
SELECT "CUSTOMERZIP" TYPE,
    CUSTOMERS.customerZip,
    COUNT(*)
FROM SALES
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON SALES.customerID = CUSTOMERS.customerID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.customerZip
) CS
ORDER BY CS.TYPE DESC, CS.COUNTS DESC
```

Comment: Just tried this. Executes without Error, but the counts are incorrect. It's basically listing each vehicle model multiple times and the count is 1 for each instance, instead of listing the vehicle model once and the count being 5 or 6, etc. The same is happening for the Zip codes. Lists the same zip multiple times, but the count is 1.

Comment: That's what I was talking about in my comment on the question. If you group by model and zip, you'll get each model and zip combination count. Do you just need to add the two lists together one after the other?

Comment: yes - let's try that. They don't have to be in the same list. Separate is fine, I think I was trying to accomplish something else that wasn't too wise. How would I show them as two separate lists in one **SELECT** statement?

Comment: Getting an error on the updated code. SP2-0042 unknown command "UNION". Also, this wouldn't be a single **SELECT** statement any longer, which is essential for this

Comment: You can put a `SELECT * FROM ( .... )` around this query to make it a single select. Edited answer to address UNION issue.

Comment: Gotcha on the SELECT* FROM(...), but the UNION ALL still is giving me the SP2-0042 error. Do you think it has something to do with being in an ORACLE DB via NOVA?

Comment: Try to remove the blank lines between the UNION and the queries.

Comment: Removed the blanks, and now I'm getting ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended. Should it have quotes or a ","?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164217/discussion-between-clinomaniac-and-stevenc).